# direction isn't working as expected

Tags: css, direction

I am wondering why direction ltr isn't working on this site. I have changed the direction in div and html tag to ltr but it is still rtl. [here](http://www.espeli.ir/c/en/5/Sci-Tech)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because element with class `.content` has `text-align` property set to the `right`. If you remove this property you can see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You should get rid of `direction: rtl;` and `text-align: right;` in http://www.espeli.ir/files/espeli.css

Or, if those are required for other pages, override them on your page.